# Examples of orthogonal/orthonormal functions which are not finite degree polynomials?

Tags: soft-question, big-list, orthogonal-polynomials

I've been reading "Fourier Series & Orthogonal Polynomials" by Dunham Jackson. Great introductory read for anyone interested by the way!

My question is, what are other examples of Orthogonal Functions, with respect to a weight function if necessary, which are not finite degree polynomials?

Jackson's book gives the Bessel functions as one example, e.g.

$$\int_0^1 xJ_0(\lambda x)J_0(\mu x)dx = 0.$$

It also discusses the $\sin $ and $\cos $ functions of course.
The other examples are finite degree polynomials including Legendre, Jacobi, Hermite, and Laguerre polynomials.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Start with any continuous differential positive function $p$ on $[0,1]$, any integrable function $q$, and a continuous positive weight function $w$. Let $\alpha,\beta \in [0,\pi)$ be given. Then there are infinitely many real values of $\lambda$, say $\lambda_{0} < \lambda_{1} < \lambda_{2} < \cdots$, for which non-trivial solutions of the following problem exist:
$$
                      -(pf')'+q = \lambda w f,\\
                       \cos\alpha f(0)+\sin\alpha f'(0)=0,\\
                       \cos\beta f(1)=\sin\beta f'(1) = 0.
$$
These solutions $\{ f_{n} \}_{n=0}^{\infty}$, when normalized so that $\int_{0}^{1}f_{n}^{2}w dx=1$, form a complete orthonormal basis of the weighted space $L^{2}_{w}[0,1]$ whose inner-product is $(f,g)_{w}=\int_{0}^{1}fgwdx$.

Comment: Ah I see. Is this related to the so-called Schmidt process? (related to Gram-Schmidt by any chance...)

Comment: The eigenfunctions for different eigenvalues are automatically orthogonal, just as they are for selfadjoint matrices. It's only when explicit functions you know about are involved that you can obtain the solutions by Gram-Schmidt instead. For the general $w$, $p$, $q$, that's not generally an option.

Comment: For those seeking more detail, google "Sturm–Liouville theory"

Answer (score 2):

Check this set

> $$ \left\{ 1,\sin(x),\cos(x),\sin(2x),\cos(2x),\dots \right\} $$

with inner product defined as

> $$\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) g(x) dx. $$

Answer (score 1):

I think the most common one is: $(e^{inx})_{n \in \mathbb{N}}$, with inner product:

Letting $e_n(x) := e^{inx}$,

$<f, e_n>=\frac{1}{2\pi}\int_{-\pi}^{\pi} f(x) e^{-inx} dx$.

$e^{-inx}$ means complex conjugation, and we integrate these because $\sum$ becomes $\int$ when continuous. $\frac{1}{2\pi}$ is for normalization.

Actually, this is the same as Benghorbal's answer.